# Include like but with variable instead of file

Tags: php

Something like this works:

```
<?php
  //some variables
  include('/myfile.php');
```

myfile.php have some html + php code. Now imagine the content of myfile.php is -for reasons not relevant to this question- inside a php variable. The immediate solution is to use `eval('?>'.$myFileInAVar.'<?php;');` instead of include, but the *scope* change when you use it and mess with some functions I have inside myfile.php.

Is there a way to replicate the behavior of include not using a file but the content of it stored in a variable?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948395/require-include-into-variable

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode please read again my question, im not interested on saving the file into a var

Comment: Ah you're right I read it wrong, this should be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389361/include-code-from-a-php-stream

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: **IT IS A SLIPPERY SLOPE AND IS NOT RECOMMENDED TO ANYONE**

If you have `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` enabled, you can use any valid wrapper, e.g. `data://` :

```
<?php
$var = '<?php $a = 18;';

include("data://text/plain;base64,".base64_encode($var));

var_dump($a);  // output: int(18)
```